# Why is the length of an html collection coming as zero?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, htmlcollection

When I am using the length property over the HTML Collection,I am getting zero...Please Correct me someone..

My HTML Code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>To Do List</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="todos">
            <ul class="todolist">
                <li class="listItem">
                    <p>Doing Homework</p>
                </li>
                <li class="listItem">
                    <p>Doing Competitve Programming</p>
                </li>
                <li class="listItem">
                    <p>Doing Dynamic Programming</p>
                </li>
                <li class="listItem">
                    <p>Doing Robot Programming</p>
                </li>
                <li class="listItem">
                    <p>Doing DSA</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

MY JS Code:

```
function crossAdder() {
    var todolist = document.getElementsByClassName('.listItem');
    console.log(todolist.length);
}
crossAdder();
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('.listItem');` is not right.

Here you're saying the class is called `.listItem`.
The class is called `listItem`. In css you address this class with the `.` notation before the class name.

Comment: @Phil Thanks,I corrected it but still it shows the same.When I corrected it,even then it gives me a zero length.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.` in `.listItem` when you input to `document.getElementsByClassName` function.

It accept a class name, not a CSS selector.

```js
function crossAdder() {
  var todolist = document.getElementsByClassName('listItem');
  console.log(todolist.length);
}
crossAdder();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="todos">
    <ul class="todolist">
      <li class="listItem">
        <p>Doing Homework</p>
      </li>
      <li class="listItem">
        <p>Doing Competitve Programming</p>
      </li>
      <li class="listItem">
        <p>Doing Dynamic Programming</p>
      </li>
      <li class="listItem">
        <p>Doing Robot Programming</p>
      </li>
      <li class="listItem">
        <p>Doing DSA</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks,I corrected it but still it shows the same.When I corrected it,even then it gives me a zero length.

Comment: @VatsalAMehta Did you click on `Run code snippet`? It will show in console is 5.

Comment: Here its showing 5 but on my browser's console it gives 0.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function crossAdder(){

   //Use query selector if you are using .listItem
   var todoList = document.querySelectorAll(".listItem")

   //If you are using getElementsByClassName don't use the dot only need just listItem
   var todoList = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem")

   console.log(todoList)
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I corrected it but still it shows the same.When I corrected it,even then it gives me a zero length.

Comment: I tried this but in my browsers console it still gives 0. @MuhsinNeyyathur